# How can I merge duplicate rows with foreign key constraints?

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to rack my brain on this for the past four hours, and I'm in a state of confusion, so I'm wondering if you'd be able to help me?

I have two tables.

**Staff**

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clerk_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `staff`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);
```

**Transactions**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `till_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_journal` mediumtext,
  `journal_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `staff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_person_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_table` varchar(255) DEFAULT '''0''',
  `gross_total` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_tax_total` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_discount_total` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_non_add` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `journal_training` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_bill_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_room_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_cancel_sale` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `journal_receipt_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `job_index` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `transactions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`journal_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `staff` (`staff_id`);


ALTER TABLE `transactions`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `transactions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `staff` FOREIGN KEY (`staff_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**What I'm looking to achieve...**
My staff table contains ~3,000 rows, some of which have multiple duplicates, for arguments sake lets say:

```
+------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
| id   | alias | first_name | last_name | clerk_code |
+------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
|    9 |       | Manager    | a         | 3597       |
|   10 |       | Manager    | a         | 3597       |
|   11 |       | Manager    | a         | 3597       |
|   16 |       | Manager    | b         | 9999       |
|  436 |       | Manager    | c         | 3126       |
| 1230 |       | Manager    | c         | 3126       |
| 1231 |       | Manager    | c         | 3126       |
| 1232 |       | Manager    | c         | 3126       |
| 1354 |       | Manager    | a         | 3597       |
+------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Now each staff row has multiple transactions (~14,000,000 rows in total), I want to be able merge / delete my duplicate staff rows and update the relative rows in transactions, keeping that association so that staff_id is now the only record in existence for each staff member.

I feel like there must be an easy way to achieve this and I'm over complicating it in my mind, if you wouldn't mind providing me with an example query and talking me through it so I can learn from it I would really appreciate that. Also if you need me to clarify anything please ask.

*Edit: I'd just like to add that I know the data types for each column are rough, this is only a temporary database as part of a migration.*

Comment: How are you deciding which of the duplicate staff records is the right one?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It wouldn't matter, could be any of the records, based on first_name, last_name and clerk_code being unique (for the purpose of this, ignore alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new `transaction_v2` table and fill it like this:

```
INSERT INTO `transaction_v2`
SELECT
    t.`id`,
    t.`date`,
    t.`till_id`,
    t.`raw_journal`,
    t.`journal_id`,
    (SELECT MIN(s2.id)
     FROM staff s2
     WHERE s2.clerk_code = s.clerk_code) staff_id
    t.`customer_id`,
    t.`journal_person_count`,
    t.`journal_table`,
    t.`gross_total`,
    t.`journal_tax_total`,
    t.`journal_discount_total`,
    t.`journal_non_add`,
    t.`journal_training`,
    t.`journal_bill_id`,
    t.`journal_room_id`,
    t.`journal_cancel_sale`,
    t.`journal_receipt_id`,
    t.`job_index`
FROM staff s
INNER JOIN transactions t ON t.staff_id = s.id
```

Then you would rename the original `transactions` to something like `transactions_OLD` (and disable the foreign key to avoid issues when you clean up `staff` later), and `transactions_v2` to `transactions`. The size of the original `transactions` table could be an issue depending on your indexes, so you might want to keep an eye on the performance. You could even work in batches, `SELECT`ing and `INSERT`ing only records related to smaller subsets of `staff_id`s each time (something like `WHERE s.id BETWEEN x AND y`).

Once the new table is in place, you can clean up the `staff` table keeping only the lowest ids and you should be good to go.

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking of using a temporary table, but hadn't thought about a temporary transactions table, was looking at the staff table. This could be the way forward. In terms of performance I'm not too fussed, this is simply a migration and not in a production environment. I'll have play with this later this evening. Thank you for the guidance, Aioros!